# What algorithms and data structures exist for describing and manipulating the boundries of superpixels and image segments efficiently?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm aware of chain coding the directions taken when tracing the edge of a region, and for lack of the correct terminology 'flood fill' where a unique region identifier is written to every cell inside the perimeter but would like to know some more options with there memory vs CPU trade offs (I have been reading over various superpixel papers but unfortunately this part usually just seems to be glossed over as an implementation detail)?

Comment: Searching the Internet for "superpixel segmentation algorithms" turns up a number of hits and implementations. I presume the implementations must have representations of the superpixel boundaries and that some manipulate them as they're being defined. If you want to see the 'implementation details' read some of the details in the published implementations.

Comment: All the usual region representations and their operations... Select based on the problem at hand: pixmaps, edge chains, indexed span lists, quadtrees. You're right that the characteristics of these are so well known that they'd be considered an implementation detail in a paper on image segmentation.